# Replace all sub-domains in a file with the another domain name using sed & wildcard

Tags: text-processing, sed

Replace all sub-domain names in a file with a different domain name using wildcard.

Ex : In a file, I have the following domains :

```
example1.domain1.com    
example2.domain1.com 
example3.domain1.com
```

I want to replace these sub-domain names with **domain2.com**. I tried using the below sed command. It works fine if the file size is small. But for large file it looks like the command execution never ends. I want to use a wildcard here since the text to be replaced have the same domain name i.e domain1.com.

```
sed -i s/.*.domain1.com/domain2.com/g test.txt
```

Comment: What size of file are you dealing with that is "too large" for the command to finish?  Also, how long did you give it?  `ls -lh` should tell you the file size in a human readable format.

Comment: I think this should do https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/263233

Comment: File size is around 70M and some files are even larger than that. I waited for around 15mins, but it did not complete. Hence, I did that in vim.

Comment: @dpb, is there any way that I can use wildcard. Since, the sub-domain names are different.

Comment: @RajeshKeladimath best to modify your question so it contains this detail, and ask for help with your pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `.*.domain1.com` as your pattern, you will essiantially match unwanted characters, because `.` means **any** character.
You want to replace only "word characters" (ASCII letters, digits or underscore) using `\w+`.

As normal `sed` regex doesn't know about `+`, make sure to add `-r` for `sed` to use extended regex.

Also make sure you use quotation marks! Otherwise `*` might be interpreted by bash.
And you should escape `.` in the pattern, otherwise it will also match any character.

```
sed -i.bak -r 's/\w+\.domain1\.com/domain2.com/g' file
```

Comment: sed allows `\w` in [both BREs and EREs](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#regexp-extensions), but the `+` needs ERE.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed -i 's/domain1/domain2/' infile`.

If you want to replace `*.domain1.com` then change like:

```
sed 's/.*domain1/domain2/' infile
```

Make sure at first attempt don't use `-i` which will replace in-place in your file.

Comment: I want to replace *.domain1.com to domain2.com.

Answer (score 0):

Open file in vi editor. Then type below mentioned command on line mode of vi editor:

```
#vi file_name 
example1.domain1.com
example2.domain1.com 
example3.domain1.com

:%s/domain1/domain2/g  hit enter now
```

Done!!

Note: domain1 is already existing string.
domain2 is a new string.